# How do I tell python the whole value is a string? since my excel formula has apostrophe in it

Tags: python, excel, string, google-sheets

In python

```
formula = "=sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!F:F, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1") - sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!G:G, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1"

print (formula)
```

I GET!!

```
File "inventory change formula", line 52
    formula = "=sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!F:F, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1") - sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!G:G, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1""
                                                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My question is how do i tell python the whole value is a string because my formula has apostrophes in it??

Comment: try to add escape character \before ".

Answer (score 1):

Use escape character

```
formula = "=sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!F:F, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, \"=1\",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,\"=A\",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,\"=1\") - sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!G:G, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, \"=1\",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,\"=A\",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,\"=1"

print (formula)
```

Output

```
=sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!F:F, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1") - sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!G:G, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Start and end your whole string with `'''`(triple quotes).

```
>>> formula = '''=sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!F:F, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1") - sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!G:G, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1'''
```

**Output:**

```
'=sumifs(\'INVENTORY IN AND OUT\'!F:F, \'INVENTORY IN AND OUT\'!E:E, "=1",\'INVENTORY IN AND OUT\'!D:D,"=A",\'INVENTORY IN AND OUT\'!C:C,"=1") - sumifs(\'INVENTORY IN AND OUT\'!G:G, \'INVENTORY IN AND OUT\'!E:E, "=1",\'INVENTORY IN AND OUT\'!D:D,"=A",\'INVENTORY IN AND OUT\'!C:C,"=1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the inverted commas appropriately. Also, I did notice that you have forgotten the last parenthese in the string.

Try tris:

```
formula = "=sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!F:F, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, \"=1\",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,\"=A\",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,\"=1\") - sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!G:G, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, \"=1\",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,\"=A\",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,\"=1\")"

print(formula)
```

Output:

```
=sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!F:F, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1") - sumifs('INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!G:G, 'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!E:E, "=1",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!D:D,"=A",'INVENTORY IN AND OUT'!C:C,"=1")
```